# What it the correct type/format for second argument for inet_ntop?

Tags: c, ip-address, posix

I used to think the second argument for `inet_ntop` should always be a `struct in_addr` or `struct in6_addr`. But then I looked up the [POSIX definition](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_ntop.html):

```
const char *inet_ntop(int af, const void *restrict src,
                      char *restrict dst, socklen_t size);
```

> [...] The *src* argument points to a buffer holding an IPv4 address if the *af* argument is AF_INET, or an IPv6 address if the *af* argument is AF_INET6; the address must be in network byte order. [...]

As you can see both the function prototype and the description are vague.

Why is this? And what are allowed/portable choices for `src`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pointer to an IPv4 or IPv6 as stored in the respective headers - so a 4 byte buffer in the case of IPv4, and a 16 byte buffer in the case of IPv6.

`struct in_addr` and `struct in6_addr` are convenient structures for storing such addresses, but you could use `unsigned char [4]` and `unsigned char [16]` respectively, if you wanted.

Comment: In that case, `struct in_addr` or `struct in6_addr` would only work if the IP address is the first member. Is this a POSIX requirement? I could not find a reference for this.

Comment: @schot: That's a good point - I suppose that technically means you need to pass the address of the `s_addr` and/or `s6_addr` members of those structs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will use `in_addr_t ` and `uint8_t [16]`, the types of the `s(6)_addr` members.